# Removing field from request still fails validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have a project running on Laravel 5.2 that has an API.

I have been requested to make a provision in the API for the API to "fix" the request if it would fail validation.

When a `POST` request is made with a query string value of `fix=true` then the API should fix the request if it knows how to fix it.

An example, my API accepts a `POST` request to create a recipe and one of these fields is `recipe_style_id`.

If an invalid value is supplied for `recipe_style_id` and the query string contains `fix=true` then I am expected to remove that field from the request so that it can be evaluated for validation without that field.

I am opting to do this inside the form request:

```
public function rules()
{
    if ($this->input('fix')) $this->fixRecipe();

    dd($this->all());

    return [
        //other validation rules...

        'recipe_style_id' => 'nullable|exists:recipe_styles,sub_category_id',
    ];
}

protected function fixRecipe()
{
    $input = $this->all();

    if (isset($input["recipe_style_id"]) && $this->isInvalidRecipeStyleId($input["recipe_style_id"])) {
        $input = array_except($input, 'recipe_style_id');
    }
    $this->replace($input);
}

protected function isInvalidRecipeStyleId($recipe_style_id)
{
    return !RecipeStyle::where('sub_category_id', $recipe_style_id)->exists();
}
```

This appears to work, if an invalid `recipe_style_id` is provided then when I view the result of the `dd()` I do not see that field in the request - however if I remove the `dd()` statement, it still fails validation on that field.

The `nullable` validation rule didn't exist in Laravel 5.2 and so I have added it into my `AppServiceProvider`:

```
Validator::extend('nullable', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    return true;
});
```

With the field no longer in the request, why is this still failing validation?

It is worth noting that if I send a `POST` request without the `recipe_style_id` then the recipe passes validation and is created successfully.

Comment: Instead of `nullable`, does `sometimes` work?

Comment: @csb tried that just after posting, it doesn't.

Comment: Your version of `nullable` field doesn't do the same as default one. It doesn't prevent the next rule from triggering

Comment: @devk damn. Do you know if it is a trivial change to emulate that behavior?

Comment: No, but you probably want to play with [sometimes custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules). The part that starts with `$v->sometimes('reason', ...)` looks promising

Comment: Untested, but it might work: https://pastebin.com/gC2gv0Np

Comment: Hmm...strange. I would've thought `sometimes` would work after doing a cursory look at [Laravel's code here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L587)

Comment: Actually, after looking at Laravel's code again, I realised it doesn't. Sorry.

Comment: Is `sub_category_id` is refer to `recipe_style_id` ?

Comment: Share your code where you are using rules , the validation ?

Comment: @C2486 yea `sub_category_id` is referring to `recipe_style_id`. This is validation is inside a request so I just validate it using this in the controller.